# Adding custom HTML element inside template using functions Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom, vuejs3

Is there any way to render html element with custom properties inside template tag using javascript functions?

Example what I try to achieve:

```
<template>
  <div class="test">
    {{ testFunction(param1,param2,param3) }}
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
....
  methods: {
    testFunction(param1,param2,param3) {
      return `<button @click="function()">Click</button>`;
   }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly you will get interpolated html, like this

```
<button @click="function()">Click</button>
```

Even if you fix it using the [`v-html` directive](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-html) to output [raw HTML](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#raw-html) the button will still not work.

The **right way** is to use [Render Functions](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#render-functions-jsx) like this:

```
const myComponent3 = {   
  setup(props) {
    return () => h('button',  
      {
        onClick(event) {
          alert('Click');
        }
      },
      'Click Me!'
    )
  }
}
```

Here is the playground with samples:

```js
const { createApp, h } = Vue;

const myComponent1 = {   
  template: '#my-component',
  methods: {
    testFunction(par1) {
      return `<button @click="function()">Click</button>`;
    }
  }
}

const myComponent2 = {   
  template: '<div v-html="rawHTML()"></div>',
  methods: {
    myClick() {    
      alert('Click');
    },
    rawHTML(par1) {
      return '<button @click="myClick()">Click</button>';
    }
  }
}

const myComponent3 = {   
  setup(props) {
    return () => h('button',  
      {
        onClick(event) {
          alert('Click');
        }
      },
      'Click Me!'
    )
  }
}

const App = {
  components: { 
    myComponent1,  myComponent2, myComponent3
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">  
  My Component 1: <my-component1></my-component1><br/>
  My Component 2: <my-component2></my-component2><br/>
  My Component 3: <my-component3></my-component3><br/>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="my-component">
  <div class="test">
    {{ testFunction( param1 ) }}
  </div>
</script>
```