# Vue2 @click doesn't work with v-html in another component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a sign up form and there is an Alert component to show the errors, one of the conditionals is "You already have an account click here to log in".

but the error messages are strings that are passed as props for the component "Alert" and the actions "click here" is a link.

```html
<!-- Parent.vue -->
<Alert v-if="!!errorField" :message="errorList[errorField].message" />
```

here it is the message

```js
// Parent.vue
errorList = {
   hasAuth: {
      message: `You already have an account <a @click.prevent="hasAuthClick()">click here</a> to log in`
   }
}
```

the Alert component is simple it just recieve the message as prop and render with v-html

```html
<!-- Child.vue -->
<span v-html="message"></span>
```

By investigations, I just realize that the link is not being compiled by vue, and that's why  I can't use the @click on it, but I don't know how to make vue to compile.

Answer (score 1):

It will not work with  [`v-html` directive](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-html) and you should use Vue [Slots](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html) or [Render Functions](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#render-functions-jsx)

I would rather use `Slots` for this.

```
Alert.vue

<template>
   <div>
     <slot>default slot</slot>
     <slot name="message">message slot</slot>
   </div>
</template>
```

and then

```
<alert>
   default slot content
   <template #message>
     You already have an account <a @click.prevent="hasAuthClick()">click here</a> to log in
   </template>
</alert>
```

Pay attention, the function `hasAuthClick()` should be defined outside `Alert.vue`, in the parent component/app.

Check my another antwort for the `Render Functions`

[Adding custom HTML element inside template using functions Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75309789/2487565)